# Python with sh.git

Tags: python, sh, python-watchdog

This is my first "real" python script so don't be too hard on me :)

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

1. A change in a network switch is made and the switch automatically sends out its current configuration to an FTP server.
2. With iNotify/Watchdog, I look at the directory and when a new .gz file comes from the switch, I unpack it and do a git add and git commit on the unpacked file.

This works for a switch when it commits its first file, and I see the configuration in our gitlab server. When a second file comes from the same switch, it overwrites the previous one, just like I want, but the second file gets stuck and a 'git add .' never happens. Is there some type of filelock that interferes with this or?

Below you will find my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
import gzip
import os
import re
import shutil
import time
from pathlib import Path

import sh
from datetime import datetime
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer


class Watcher:
    def __init__(self, directory, handler=FileSystemEventHandler()):
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.handler = handler
        self.directory = directory
        
    def run(self):
        self.observer.schedule(self.handler, self.directory, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()
        print("\nWatcher Running in {}/\n".format(self.directory))
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
        self.observer.join()
        print("\nWatcher Terminated\n")

class FsHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):    
    
    
    """
    Purpose: React on file creation
    Event: created
    Action: log and unzip
    Condition: if file ends with juniper.conf.gz
    """
    def on_created(self, event):
        print("on_created")
        if event.src_path.endswith("juniper.conf.gz"):
            print(self.__cleanup(event.src_path))
        if event.src_path.endswith("juniper.conf"):
            # Start revision handling
            sh.git.add("-A")
            sh.git.commit("-m", str(datetime.now()))
            sh.git.push().wait()
                       
    
    """
    Purpose: React on file moving/renaming
    Event: moved
    Action: log and commit to git
    Condition: -NONE-
    """
    def on_moved(self, event):
        print("on_moved")
        # decompress the gzip file
        with gzip.open(event.dest_path, 'rb') as f_in:
            with open(re.sub('.gz$', '', event.dest_path),'wb') as f_out:
                shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                f_out.close()
        
        # remove the gzip file version
        os.remove(event.dest_path);
        
    """
    Purpose: React on file deletion
    Event: deleted
    Action:  log
    Condition: -NONE-
    """
    def on_deleted(self, event):
        print("on_deleted")
        print("Filename: " + Path(str(event.src_path)).name)
    
    """
    Purpose: Remove date and time from file
    Reason: Otherwise each config file will have its own commit,
             no matter it comes from the same switch.
    """
    def __cleanup(self, old_filename):
        new_filename = re.sub('_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_juniper.conf.gz', '_juniper.conf.gz', old_filename)
        os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Default path to watch is current dir
    watch_path='.'
    
    # Handle arguments from commandline
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="autocommit.py",
        description="Autocommit Junos configuration from our switches to git repo",
        epilog="(c)2022 Roger Nordqvist <roger.nordqvist@filipstad.se>"
        )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-p", "--path", help="Specify path to watch"
        )
    
    # Parse commandline options
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.path:
        watch_path=args.path
        print(watch_path) 

    # move script execution to the path we are watching
    os.chdir(watch_path)

    w = Watcher(watch_path, FsHandler())
    w.run()
```

I've tried more or less everything but I am new to Python so ...

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit with the `tried more or less everything` part?

Comment: Have you tried running manually the git commands?

Comment: Yes, what I don't understand is why the first incoming file unpacks just fine and commits as expected. It also get pushed to the Repo. De second incoming from the same switch also unpacks but dont get staged with git add . or git add -A.

Comment: What happens if you run `git add -v .` or `git add -vA`?

Comment: I console mode without the script?

Comment: or within the script if you can capture the output. I've got the feeling git could hang at analysing big files, specially if they're not plain text (which i dont know)

Comment: The biggest config file I got is 119290 bytes so I guess it aint large.